# Parallax page with color changing text

Tags: html, css, parallax, styling

I want to make a page with a big text across the screen and if you scroll, the background colors change (it could be done with images aswell)

I've tried a lot but i cant get it working...

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>testhtml</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        html, body{
            height: 100%;
        }
        .parallax{

            background-image: url(../assets/img/img1.jpg);
            min-height: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
        }
        .title { 
            overflow:hidden;
            display:inline-block; 
            padding:10px; 
            font-weight:bold;
            font-family:arial;
            color:transparent;
            font-size:200px;
        }span { 
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            display:block;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="parallax">
                <h1 class="title"><span>Test</span></h1>

    </div>
</body>
```

it shows the text with image as background, but when you scroll the images stays, because its fixed i think.

But it should be the image staying and the background scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the text somewhere constant on the page,you need fixed position which will force the element to stay always in a certain position

This fixed class always will force the text in the center.

```
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
      top:40%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here you can see my solution : https://codepen.io/Cicek96/pen/qBdNVBO

Comment: It's close. But what i need is that the text stays in the middle of the page all the time and changes color when you scroll. So i wanted to make a black background with a cutout transparent text (like 
 https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cutout_text.asp but when you scroll the text needs to stay)so you would only see the stuff arround the text and not the text itself untill you put a background behind it. But thanks for your help

Comment: @TibbeN. okay I got your question now.You need fixed position on your text.I updated the link on the answer you can check.Please mark this as an answer if satisfied your requirement

Comment: that works, but than i need the text to be a cutout... So you have a black page with a transparent text that shows the background, But i think i can get it working now, Thanks